# Estructuras de Control Repetitivas

Tags: javascript

[image: Codigo escrito]

```
function Ejercicio5() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 450; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
        }
        document.querySelector("#pResultado5").innerHTML += i + " ";
    }
}
```

Necesito mostrar los números entre 1 y 450 que sean múltiplos de 5 al oprimir un botón. Cree mi código, funciona pero solo me muestra los números entre 1 y 450 pero no los múltiplos de 5. Necesito ayuda, gracias!

Comment: ¿Quieres que te lo hagamos de cero o nos vas a mostrar lo que has hecho para que te ayudemos a entenderlo y arreglarlo?  Lo digo porque aquí no hacemos código a medida, sino que arreglamos el código del que pregunta, pero tu no has puesto ninguno, por lo tanto poco se te puede ayudar. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y a como elaborar buenas preguntas, gracias.

Comment: Disculpa y gracias por la ayuda, ahí agregue una imagen para que sea más claro

Comment: Vale, no vas mal, pero en este sitio el código se pega como texto, no como imagen, porque sino nos cuesta mucho más ayudarte si tenemos que teclearlo todo para reproducir tu error y buscarte una solución.  Una vez lo peges como texto puedes marcarlo como código pulsando el botón `{}` del editor para que se vea bien.

Comment: Gracias Master, ahi la deje como me solicitaste. Te agradezco

Comment: Mírate la parte final de la respuesta de @ArcanisGK507.  Casi lo tenias, tan solo necesitabas mover ese innerHTML dentro del bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si es multiplo de 5, personalmente considero que debe ser tambien divisible entre 5: OJO que va dentro del IF tu condicion... no Afuera.

```js
let c=1
while(c<=450)
{
  if(c%5===0){
    console.log(c);
    // tu codigo
    document.querySelector("#pResultado5").innerHTML += i + " ";
  }
  c++;
}
```

como veras uso el operador de modulo `%` y valido que el resultado sea identico `===` a `0` en el caso anterior usando un `while` tambien puedes hacerlo con un `for`

***implementacion:***

```
function Ejercicio5() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 450; i++) {
        if (i % 5 === 0) {
            document.querySelector("#pResultado5").innerHTML += i + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Arcanis! Crack!